# Trying to implement Bedmas functionality into my code

Tags: java, math, compiler-construction, operator-precedence

So I am basically trying to create an intermediate code generation in java. My code will take in user input and will try to print out the intermediate code generation representation of the code for example:

```
theinputwillbe: 5+5/3 
output will be: t1=5/3 
                t2=5+t1
```

here is the sample code

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String str1;
      Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.println("Enter String (Containing 0 to 9 and/or operators: +,/,*,-)");
    str1 = str.nextLine();
     int len1=str1.length();
     int pp, pp2, pp0,j=0;
     for(pp=0;pp<len1;pp++)
      {     
          if (pp+1 == len1) pp2 = len1-1; else pp2 = pp+1;
          if( str1.charAt(pp) == '/') {char t11 = str1.charAt(pp-1); char t12= str1.charAt(pp+1);  
          j++; System.out.println("t"+j+"= " + t11 + str1.charAt(pp) + t12); }
         if( str1.charAt(pp) == '*') {char t11 = str1.charAt(pp-1); char t12= str1.charAt(pp+1); 
           j++; System.out.println("t"+j+"= " + t11 + str1.charAt(pp) + t12); }
         if( str1.charAt(pp) == '+') {char t11 = str1.charAt(pp-1); char t12= str1.charAt(pp+1); 
           j++; System.out.println("t"+j+"= " + t11 + str1.charAt(pp) + t12); }
         if( str1.charAt(pp) == '-') {char t11 = str1.charAt(pp-1); char t12= str1.charAt(pp+1); 
          j++; System.out.println("t"+j+"= " + t11 + str1.charAt(pp) + t12); }
         //j++;
         }
        }
      }
```

This is the output i am getting

```
Enter String (Containing 0 to 9 and/or operators: +,/,*,-)
5+5/3
t1= 5+5
t2= 5/3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The output i am getting is incorrect because its not following the rules of BEDMAS The correct way  it should be is:

```
t1=5/3
t2=5+t1
```

Could someone please assist me to fix this code so it prints out the output the correct way

Comment: The correct output would be `t1 = 5 / 3` then `t2 = 5 + t1`. `5+5` is wrong wherever it appears.

Comment: @rici yes you are correct but in that case, could you demonstrate how to do it correctly through the use of code cause I'm still not sure how to implement it in java.

Comment: First suggestion: separate the logic for identifying input tokens (numbers, operators, parentheses) from the parser and the code generator. You have three separate tasks; keep them separate. For the parser, there are lots of relevant questions here already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Shunting+yard+java